# SharePoint Workflow to send Email on a specific Date and Time

Tags: email, sharepoint, workflow

I am working on a SharePoint list to maintain the regular yearly maintenance activities in the organization.

The list contains, Activity Name, Status, Reminder Date, Next Maintenance Date, Primary Contact. (The Date variables are defined as Date and Time)

Basically what I want to do is Send an Email on the Reminder Date and Time (Ex: 05/09/2013 11:00 AM)

So I created a workflow to check for the date & Time and wait till the Time is reached to send the Email as below:

```
Condition: If ReminderDate is greater than or equal to Today
        and Status not equal Completed
Action: Wait for ReminderDate to equal Today
        then Email PrimaryContact
```

But the workflow is just sitting in In Progress state waiting for Reminder Date.

I am pretty much on the learning curve at SharePoint and I am learning as I go.
Please help me with any inputs to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a 'Pause Until' condition in your case to send out mails on a specified date only. I would like to suggest you to create a custom Timer Job instead of a designer workflow. In your case, using a 'Pause Until' condition would be a much more resource consuming process and definitely it will have an impact on your site performance

Comment: Thank you Aniket. I am presently using Pause until, Where as would like to know if it is ok to use in this format for longer time period, like for a yearly maintenance activity the workflow would be there in pause mode for a year max. What would be the load on the site as I am expecting couple of thousand records in the list.

Comment: Hi jats, why don't you create a custom Timer Job instead of a designer workflow? In your case, using a 'Pause Until' condition would be a much more resource consuming process and definitely it will have an impact on your site performance.

Comment: Hi Aniket, I have a similar question, but my workflow is not from a list, but calendar, Please see and advice - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073154/sharepoint-designer-create-workflow-to-schedule-emails-on-specific-dates-from

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your task by using SharePoint designer.

Follow these steps:

- Create a list having all your fields i.e. Activity Name, Status, Reminder Date , Next Maintenance Date, Primary Contact.
- Reminder Date field should be Date & time type and format should be Date only.
- Open this list in SharePoint designer.
- Write a condition given below: 
  [image]
- Add a user.
- Publish it.

Comment: Good answer, only sometimes this approach can get all the other workflows in the same list to be stuck. Therefore, I would suggest adding the above is a separate workflow. That sis the trick for me when my workflows got stuck because of "pause until". (mine is 2010 workflow on SP2013).

Comment: Hi Adi, I have a similar question, but my workflow is not from a list, but calendar, Please see and advice - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47073154/sharepoint-designer-create-workflow-to-schedule-emails-on-specific-dates-from

Comment: i tried this but i dont get any emails   can you please help me
sp document library

Answer (score 0):

I had a bit of more research after the post and found some links similar to my problem and changed the workflow as below with the help of information in my research...

```
Steps
If Status equals Completed
    Stop Stop Workflow and Log

If ReminderDate equals Today
    Send Email Primary Contact

Else If ReminderDate greater than Today
    Pause until ReminderDate
    Send Email Primary Contact
```

So till now it worked well, I am posting this here so that if any one can find any issues in the solution you can let me know of the same.

Thank you